# Entity Framework MySQL Create Index Name With Tilde(~)

Tags: entity-framework

I have been having an issue with Entity Framework, when EF creates a SQL script, EF puts a tilde "~" at the end of the index name. The entity is created without problems, but if I made a rollback, and EF tries to drop that index, a problem occurs because MySQL can't find that index.

For example - index name is:

IX_malte_input_spend_log_porto_le_dsc_sku_cod_porto_val_mes_val~
I get this error:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30'] DROP INDEX IX_malte_input_spend_log_porto_le_dsc_sku_cod_porto_val_mes_val~ ON malte_input_spend_log_porto_le;
```

The correct SQL command needs to use `` in the name of the index to run with success.

```
DROP INDEX `IX_malte_input_spend_log_porto_le_dsc_sku_cod_porto_val_mes_val~` ON malte_input_spend_log_porto_le;
```

Does someone know how I can resolve this problem?

Thanks